# Incrementing a column value in a SQL database if there is a duplicate row

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-update

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
Number   Product    Type
 1        Meat      Cow
 1        Milk       A
```

If I insert a new row:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (Product, Type) VALUES (Meat, Cow)
```

I don't want a new row. I want the column "Number" where Product = Meat and Type = Cow be incremented by 1:

```
Number   Product    Type
 2        Meat      Cow
 1        Milk       A
```

Is there a SQL command to do this?

Comment: If you have a unique constraint on `(Product, Type)` you can use `insert on conflict do update ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following by using `ON CONFLICT` that starts from version `9.5` :

```
create table t1( Number int, 
                 Product varchar(15), 
                 Type varchar(15),
                 primary key (Product, Type)
               );

insert into t1(Number,Product,Type) values(1,'Meat','Cow');               

insert into t1(Number,Product,Type) values(1,'Meat','Cow')
on conflict (Product,Type) do update set Number = t1.Number + 1;
select * from t1;  

number  product type
------  ------- ----
  2      Meat   Cow
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/ZYWMCI32464)

where composite unique(primary) key is a must for `Product` and `Type` columns, if not exists than *42P10: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification* error raises.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use triggers to achieve what you want. Format :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON table_name
WHEN (your_condition_here) --for example, row exist 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE ... --your update query
END;
```

Comment: `instead of` triggers can only be defined on views, not on tables.

Answer (score 0):

Create Unique Index on Product and Type, then

```
INSERT INTO t1 (Product, Type) VALUES (Meat, Cow) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT <your_key> 
UPDATE set Number = Number + 1
```

Should work.